# Moving an image in the image view

Tags: android, image

I want to load an image from gallery and Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling. When click on the left, right, up and down button, the image should move in the viewing window with a step size of around 5 pixels.

Below is what I did so far

Java Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 111;
boolean imageLoaded = false;
ImageView imgView;
boolean state = false;
Button up,down,left,right;

Bitmap inputBM, outputBM;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
    left=(Button)findViewById(R.id.left);
    right=(Button)findViewById(R.id.right);
    down=(Button)findViewById(R.id.down);

    final double contrastValue = 100;



    up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imgView.getLayoutParams();
            mParams.topMargin -= 5;
            imgView.setLayoutParams(mParams);
        }
    });

    down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"DOWN",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                    imgView.getLayoutParams();
            mParams.topMargin += 20;
            imgView.setLayoutParams(mParams);

        }
    });

    left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"LEFT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                    imgView.getLayoutParams();
            mParams.leftMargin -= 20;
            imgView.setLayoutParams(mParams);
        }
    });

    right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"RIGHT",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                    imgView.getLayoutParams();
            mParams.leftMargin += 20;
            imgView.setLayoutParams(mParams);
        }
    });

}


public void loadImage(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    // Show only images, no videos or anything else
    i.setType("image/*");
    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            inputBM = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);

            imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(inputBM);
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageLoaded = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

XML code

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:onClick="loadImage"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/no_image" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/right"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/up"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_below="@+id/up"
    android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/up"
    android:text="Button" />
```

But this does not work as expected. It move the Image View instead of the image inside the image view. Please help me in this or provide any other solution to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these changes into your XML

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:onClick="loadImage"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/right"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/up"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/up"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/up"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It will still make your Image View move but your view will be the size of the image so it will give a feel that image is moving.

Comment: Thanks, it give exactly what I need